# Using $\, \,y(x_0)=y_0\,\,$ for differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I don't know what to do next, I'am trying to use the given point but as you can see tan(-pi/2) won't give me the answer that I loking for...

Answer (score 2):

In the step where you divide by $\sin(z)+1$, you're losing some solutions of the form $z(x)=C$ (constant solutions, where $\sin(C)+1=0$); these solutions need to be written down separately. And it so happens that the given initial data corresponds to one of those solutions.

Comment: I had a mistake, this is the solution: http://i.imgur.com/xB9VX6L.png

How can I find the constant C?

Comment: $y(0)=-\pi/2$ corresponds to $z(0)=0+y(0)=-\pi/2$. And since $z(x)$ is constant, you simply get $z(x)=-\pi/2$ for all $x$.

Comment: I ment the C from the integral with the tan(x+y)...

Comment: You can't, since that formula only gives the solutions whose initial value $z_0 \,(=y_0)$ is *not* a solution of $\sin(z)=-1$. (That's the whole point of my answer...)

Answer (score 1):

After the transformation $z=x+y$ you arrive to the equivalent IVP
$$
z'=\sin z+1,\quad z(0)=-\frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{1}
$$
Clearly, the constant function, $z(x)=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, satisfies $(1)$.

But IVP $(1)$ enjoys uniqueness, since $f(z)=\sin z+1$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Hence, $z(x)=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is THE solution of $(1)$, and thus $y(x)=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x$ is THE solution of the original IVP.

**Note**. This is a great example of an IVP to test the most common mistake students make when the solve separable ODEs, i.e. $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$. To avoid the mistake one needs to know the following:

*Never divide by $g(y)$, if the initial value kills $g(y)$, i.e., $g(y_0)=0.$ In such case the solution of the IVP is constant.*