# Getting rid of absolute value in integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

If I have this equation
$$|I|=e^C |x^3|$$
where $C$ is a constant, yet to be determined. Is it allowed to say:

let $A$ be a constant such that 
$$\begin{cases} A=-e^C \space\space\space if\space\space \frac{I}{x^3}<0 \\  
                A=e^C  \space\space\space\space\space\space if\space\space \frac{I}{x^3}\gt0
   \end{cases}$$

then
$$I=Ae^x$$

This is part of an integration using the integrating factor method, btw.

Comment: You meant $I=Ax^3$, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark yes

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: yes. Since $C$ is arbitrary to begin with, $A$ will then be an arbitrary *nonzero* constant.

(But how do you come across this in the context of integrating factors? The place where it usually shows up all the time is integration of ODEs by *separation of variables*.)

Comment: Well what I'm worried about is the part about A possibly being 0. I remember there being an additional step needed to cover the case where A is possible 0 but I'm not sure what it really was about.

Comment: These answers might help you with that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999899/using-yx-0-y-0-for-differential-equation/999906#999906, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980676/repairing-solutions-in-ode/980774#980774